# QSortFilterProxyModel not filtering correctly

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to filter a QTableView based on text in QLineEdit by using a QSortFilterProxyModel. It is working, although not correctly - it is not displaying items that are a "complete match". An example will better illustrate what I mean.

Example:
Typing "22" into the QLineEdit will show rows that have "22" in the first column, but not the row that has a column that is equal to 22. "229" will be shown, "2224" will be shown, but not "22"

[image: inputting 2]

[image: inputting 22]

Below is the stripped down version of my code

```
self.model = QSqlTableModel()
self.model.setTable("products")
self.model.select()

self.proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel()
self.proxy.setSourceModel(self.model)
self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(0)

self.ui.table_products.setModel(self.proxy)
self.ui.line_input.textChanged.connect(self._filter_products)

def _filter_products(self, text):
    search = QRegExp(
        text,
        Qt.CaseInsensitive,
        QRegExp.RegExp
    )

    self.proxy.setFilterRegExp(search)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are filtering on column 0...

```
self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(0)
```

...and there is only 1 row with 22 in that column.